# Proof by induction that for a complete simple and undirected graph that $|E|=\frac {n(n-1)} 2$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

> Prove with induction that for a complete simple and undirected graph that $|E|=\frac {n(n-1)} 2$

Base case is trivial.

Suppose that for a graph with $n-1$ vertices we have $|E|=\frac {(n-1)(n-2)} 2$

Prove that a graph with $n$ vertices $|E|=\frac {n(n-1)} 2$

Take out one vertex, so we have $n-1$ vertices and by the induction hypothesis:  $|E|=\frac {(n-1)(n-2)} 2$ add that vertex back and connect it with all other vertices to get $|E|=\frac {n(n-1)} 2$.

Is the part where we take out a vertex and then connect it back to all other vertices legit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the part where we take out a vertex and then connect it back to all other vertices legit?

Yes, but I think it could be a bit clearer:

- For clarity, I’d define $E_n$ to be the set of edges on such a graph with $n$ vertices. That way, in the inductive step, you can talk about $E_{n-1}$ and $E_n$ without any risk of confusion.
- Just include a line about how many edges you remove with that vertex, so that the connection between $\frac{1}{2}(n-1)(n-2)$ and $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ is clear, and it doesn’t just look like you’re jumping to the answer.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Hmm can I assume that the vertex I removed is connected to all other edges?

Comment: @kuhaku In a complete, simple and undirected graph, any one vertex is connected by an edge to all other *vertices*. And how many other vertices are there?

Comment: $n-1$, got it. I was too lazy to write that both graphs with $n$ and $n-1$ vertices are complete so I forgot about it...